# What is the highest possible amount of Thaddius' that can exist on the board?

Tags: hearthstone

With the introduction of the cards [Stalagg](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7744-stalagg) (If Feugen also died this game, summon [Thaddius](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7759-thaddius)) and [Feugen](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7745-feugen) (If Stalagg also died this game, summon [Thaddius](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/7759-thaddius)), how many Thaddius' can be summoned and be present on the board at any one time?

An interesting mechanic to this card is the effect is not unique to the owner of that card, for example: If I play a Stalagg and my opponent plays a Feugen and they both trade, a Thaddius will be summoned for us both, meaning 2 Thaddius' have been summoned.

Using **any means necessary** how many Thaddius' can exist on the board for both players?

See if you can seperate your answer into 2 parts: what is possible in a single turn and what is possible over multiple turns.

Comment: Thanks to Priest (Mind Vision), over multiple turns the number is only limited by the maximum number of Minions on the field, which is 14. No idea for 1 turn though. Without any setup, my guess is 4 (Baron Rivendare, Feugen, Stalagg, Void Terror, if you somehow get them cheap enough).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Single Turn

It is possible to get 14 Thaddius' on the board, 7 for each player. There are many ways to do this, but here is a possible scenario:

**Mage vs. Priest**

1. Priest plays Mind Vision twice, getting 2 Stalaggs.
2. Priest plays Thoughtsteal, getting 1 more Stalagg.
3. Priest draws his or her own Stalagg and Feugen and plays Feugen.
4. Mage plays Stalagg and Duplicate.
5. Mage draws Feugen.
6. Mage attacks Priest's Feugen with his or her Stalagg, producing two Thaddius' and duplicating the Mage's Stalagg.
7. At this point, both players have one Thaddius each, the Mage has three Stalagg/Fuegen's in hand and the Priest has four Stalagg/Fuegen's in hand.
8. Mage plays his or her three Stalagg/Fuegens.
9. Priest plays his or her four Stalagg/Fuegens.
10. Mage plays a Duplicate.
11. Both players kill eachother's Stalagg/Fuegens causing the Mage to get two more.
12. Mage plays his or her two remaining Stalagg/Fuegens and they die.
13. At this point, Mage has six Thaddius' and Priest has five Thaddius'.
14. Mage plays a Faceless Manipulator to complete his or her seven Thaddius set.
15. Priest plays two Faceless Manipulators to complete his or her seven Thaddius set.

## Multiple Turns

A very large number of Thaddius' can be produced over an entire game, too many for me to count. Here is why:

**Priest vs. Priest**

1. Each Priest draws a Thoughtsteal. One draws Stallag and one draws Feugen.
2. Each Priest player has a Stalagg/Feugen and a Thoughsteal as the bottom two cards of their deck.
3. Starting on turn 2 for the 2nd Priest player, each Priest player plays a Thoughtsteal every turn.
4. Every Thoughtsteal through an amazing random number generator miracle gets the bottom two cards of the opponent's deck (a Stalagg/Feugen and a replacement Thoughsteal).
5. Starting on turn 8, the Priest players start playing both a Thoughtsteal and a Stalagg or Feugen.
6. Both Priests trade Feugen and Stallagg producing Thaddius, which they then trade.

Therefore, starting on turn 9, two Thaddius' are produced every turn until one of the Priest players dies from Fatigue (which Priests can survive for a while).

Answer (score 2):

Using Kel'thuzad, baron rivendare, and reincarnate, you can theoretically have infinite. As well, you need no interaction from the other player.

So assuming no board cap (which isnt true, its capped at 7 per player).

Field: Kel'thuzad, Baron Rivendare, Stalag, Feugen.

Play reincarnate on Stalag and Feugen

Thaddius count: 2

Field: Kel'thuzad, Baron Rivendare, Stalag, Feugen, Thaddius x2

End turn, field: Kel'thuzad, Baron Rivendare, Stalag x2, Feugen x2, Thaddius x2

Proceed to crash your Stalags and Feugens to get 2x thaddius each and get them back at the end of the turn with Kel'thuzad.

Note that this would need some serious setup, and has a ridiculous mana cost and is not a realistic play in a game.

Comment: While this is a good answer and covers a great way to summon several Thaddius', it still does not answer the total possible amount of Thaddius' that can be on the field at one time. For example: both players having a Stalagg, Feugen and Baron each, trading in and getting 4 Thaddius' each. Something similar to that but using anything possible to create more Thaddius' e.g. Faceless Manipulator

Comment: But you'd need Kel'Thezud who takes up a space that a Thaddius would be using.

Comment: Dont forget mind control and Faceless Manipulaters. You get lucky as a priest. Thought steel 2x Faceless + your own. I dont see an issue in having a board full of these guys.

Comment: Why do you need the reincarnates?  You get infinite anyway without them.

Comment: If we're using thoughtsteal, 2 priests. Each use of thoughtsteal gets a Stalagg and another thoughtsteal.